# Same origin fetch leads to null comparison (HTTP CORS)

Tags: javascript, http, cors

A simple same origin `fetch("fetch.xml")` fails here with the console error message

> Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/fetch.xml' from origin
> 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: The
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
> 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have
> the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque
> response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to
> fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The corresponding network headers are

```
General
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/fetch.xml
Referrer Policy: origin

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8000
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-scripts
Content-Type: text/xml
Date: Sun, 16 Aug 2020 06:20:43 GMT
Referrer-Policy: origin
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.8.5

Request Headers
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Origin: null
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36
```

As you can see the browser (here Chrome) says Origin = null, although the origin is the same origin. I can also reproduce this with a real domain instead of the ip address, the origin of the fetch is always null according to the browser.

If I change the fetch statement to `fetch("fetch.xml", { mode: "same-origin" })` the browser still assumes null to be the origin, but the error message changes to

> Fetch API cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/fetch.xml. Request mode is
> "same-origin" but the URL's origin is not same as the request origin
> null.

How can I get the browser to work with the right origin and not null for the fetch statement? I played around with the *referrer-policy* as you can see. I do not want *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* to include null or *, as this seems too open (basically disabling CORS).

**Remark**: I am not accessing the files by `file://` URLs! This is a real web server and the origin is still null! So this question is not the same as the duplicate stackoverflow has linked to.

---

---

**Minimum Reproducing Example**

Simple server including everything if you want to test it quickly (simply run it with python3):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from http.server import HTTPServer, HTTPStatus, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, test
import sys
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os

class TestRequestHandler (SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        """Serve a GET request."""
        url = urlparse(self.path)
        if url.path == '/' or url.path == '/index.html': # index.html
            f = self.send_head('text/html')
            self.wfile.write('''<!DOCTYPE html>
                            <html>
                            <head>
                                <title>Test</title>
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="control.js"></script>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                            </body>
                            </html>'''.encode('utf-8'))
        elif url.path == '/control.js': # control.js will try to fetch the fetch.xml
            f = self.send_head('application/javascript')
            self.wfile.write('''function init() {
                    fetch("fetch.xml", { mode: "same-origin" }).then(r => r.text()).then(t => console.log(t));
                }
                window.addEventListener("load", init);'''.encode('utf-8'))
        elif url.path == '/fetch.xml': # fetch.xml
            f = self.send_head('text/xml')
            self.wfile.write('''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                            <root>
                                <test>Hi</test>
                            </root>'''.encode('utf-8'))


    def send_head(self, ctype):
        self.send_response(HTTPStatus.OK)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', ctype)
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 86400)
        self.send_header('Referrer-Policy', 'origin')
        self.send_header('Content-Security-Policy', 'sandbox allow-scripts')
        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test(TestRequestHandler, HTTPServer, port=int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 8000)
```

---

If you prefer to put it on your own server with different files:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="control.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

control.js

```js
function init() {
    fetch("fetch.xml", { mode: "same-origin" }).then(r => r.text()).then(t => console.log(t));
}
window.addEventListener("load", init);
```

fetch.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root><test>Hello</test></root>
```

The server should be set up to send the following headers (adapt the ip/domain):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8000
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Referrer-Policy: origin
Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-scripts
```

Comment: Thats why I included a webserver. It isn't working with a webserver. Even if the webserver is not locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

> ```
> Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-scripts
> ```

See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox).

You didn't enable this directive:

> **allow-same-origin**
>
> Allows the content to be treated as being from its normal origin. If
> this keyword is not used, the embedded content is treated as being
> from a unique origin.

… so `http://localhost:8000/` and `http://localhost:8000/fetch.xml` are treated as different, unique origins.

Comment: Thank you very much :-) . I've already tried to remove the CSP relevant header entirely, which didn't help and I tried default-src etc., so I thought this wouldn't change anything. I didn't think of such a flag being existent.